# How do I set up numericality for a Rails model attribute so it will accept any non-zero positive or negative value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app, and one of my models is called "Asset" with an attribute called "shares."  At first, I thought I only wanted "shares" to have a value higher than zero.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :shares, .....
  ......
  validates :shares,  presence: true, numericality: { :greater_than => 0 }
end
```

Now it turns out that I want "shares" to be able to have either positive or negative value.  The only value it CAN'T have is zero.

Is there a way for me to set "numericality" so it can be either greater than or less than zero?  Something along the lines of:

```
numericality: { :greater_than => 0, :less_than => 0  }
```

or

```
numericality: { :greater_than => 0 || :less_than => 0  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:other_than => 0`. All other numbers are either positive or negative.